# cURL No URL set

Tags: php, curl, binary

This PHP allows the user to submit a form with a URL in binary or plain text. The URL is then converted to plain text and I'm using cURL to load the response then translate it back to binary. In case you're wondering, it's from a binary translator which can translate text -> binary and binary -> text, but also accepts URLs.

**The problem**: As you can see binary URLs are translated to text then passed to cURL. The plaintext value is stored in `$newtext`. I can confirm that `binaryToText()` does work as advertised through some debugging I did. Plain text URLs (see the `else` portion of the if statement) are successfully set, but converted binary ones are not.

**Examples**

e.g. `$text = "http://google.co.uk";`
(`isBinary($text) == false`)

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $text);` <- This works

e.g. `$text = "01101000011101000111010001110000001110100010111100101111011001110110111101101111011001110110110001100101001011100110001101101111001011100111010101101011"` (same google url)
(`isBinary($text) == true`)

`$newtext = binaryToText($text);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newtext);`

`echo curl_error($ch);` -> outputs "No URL set!"

Somewhere in there is the problem... I can't see it though.

**Code listing**

```
$text = $_POST["text"];
if(startsWith($text, "http://") || startsWith($text, "https://") || startsWith($text, textToBinary("http://")) || startsWith($text, textToBinary("https://"))) {
  // URL - accepts binary (prefered), or plain text url; returns binary.
  $ch = curl_init();
  if(isBinary($text)) {
    $newtext = binaryToText($text);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newtext);
  } else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $text);
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MY USERAGENT");
  if(isset($_GET["r"])) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  echo curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo textToBinary($result);
} else if...
```

**Functions**

```
function isBinary($input) {
  return !preg_match('/[^(0|1)]/', $input); // contains nothing but 0 and 1
}
function binaryToText($input) {
  $return = '';
  $chars = explode("\n", chunk_split(str_replace("\n", '', $input), 8));
  $_I = count($chars);
  for($i = 0; $i < $_I; $return .= chr(bindec($chars[$i])), $i++);
  return $return;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Output of `$newtext` is contained in this output:

```
text: 01101000011101000111010001110000001110100010111100101111011001110110111101101111011001110110110001100101001011100110001101101111001011100111010101101011
newtext: http://google.co.uk
No URL set!00000000
```

From this:

```
if(isBinary($text)) {
  echo "text: ".$text."\n";
  $newtext = binaryToText($text);
  echo "newtext: ".$newtext."\n";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newtext);
} else {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $text);
}
```

Comment: Check your value of `$newtext = binaryToText($text)`

Comment: Hey, I added the output of `$newtext` as it appears from an echo (see the edit at the bottom of my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

There was a NUL byte in my `$newtext` variable - so while `echo`ing worked, cURL did not accept it as a valid URL. I used the following line of code in my `binaryToText()` method:

```
$return = str_replace("\0", "", $return);
```

This replaces all NUL characters with `""`. So glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

Walk through your code and do test outputs.

The most likely scenario is that your `isBinary()` function is malfunctioning.

Do a test output using

```
print_r(isBinary($text))
```

to see what it returns.

Comment: I can confirm that `isBinary()` works as intended (I removed my debugging code before posting here).

Comment: Please take a look at my edit if you have time. Any help is appreciated!