Problem sending requests to the server in WordPress
I wrote a plugin that sends a request to the crawler from the plugin and...
I brought the crawler to the server, then when I request it with local WordPress, everything is ok and it works.
But when I make a request with the site that is online, it gives this error
Error: cURL error 3: No URL set (Code: http_request_failed)
I completely disabled the server firewall
This code is also the part of sending request to the server whose address is correct
`$url = "http://185.208.175.249:8000/upload";
// Logging URL
error_log('URL: ' . $url);
echo 'URL: ' . $url . '<br>';

$dataUrl = site_url() . "/wp-json/wp/v2/prc/all_info";
echo 'Data URL: ' . $dataUrl . '<br>';

// Fetch data from the WordPress REST API
$response = wp_remote_get($dataUrl, array('timeout' => 120));

if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    error_log('Error fetching data: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    echo 'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message();
    return;
}

$data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
error_log('Fetched data: ' . $data);
echo 'Fetched data: ' . $data . '<br>';

$data_array = json_decode($data, true);

if ($data_array === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    error_log('JSON decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
    echo 'Error: JSON decode error - ' . json_last_error_msg();
    return;
}

if ($data_array) {
    $data_array['strategy'] = [['strategy' => $strategy]];
    $data = json_encode($data_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    error_log('Data being sent: ' . $data);
    echo 'Data being sent: ' . $data . '<br>';
} else {
    error_log('Invalid data format');
    echo 'Error: Invalid data format';
    return;
}

error_log('Data: ' . $data);

if (empty($url)) {
    error_log('URL is empty');
    echo 'Error: URL is empty';
    return;
}

// Send data to the external URL using POST method
$response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 300,
    'body'        => $data,
    'headers'     => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    )
));

if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    $error_code = $response->get_error_code();
    error_log('Error sending data: ' . $error_message . ' (Code: ' . $error_code . ')');
    echo 'Error: ' . $error_message . ' (Code: ' . $error_code . ')';
} else {
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    error_log('Response from server: ' . $body);
    echo 'Response from server: ' . $body;
}

}
?>
`

Can you fix the code formatting? It seems there's a mismatched curly brace, too. Also, make sure this is a [mcve] and that you include the output this creates. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

"cURL error 3: No URL set" does not sound like an issue that could have anything to do with any firewalls - the URL you specified, simply appears to be "empty", at least from cURL's point of view. Is the URL actually hard-coded, as the code shown suggests? Please make a var_dump of it, and pay attention to the reported length. If f.e. somehow a NUL byte made its way in there, that would be one possible reason for cURL to consider it "empty" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33055195/1427878)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Debugging wp_remote_post Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // Ensure the URL is properly initialized
    $url = "http://185.208.175.249:8000/upload";
    error_log('Target URL: ' . $url);
    echo 'Target URL: ' . $url . '<br>';

    if (empty($url)) {
        error_log('URL is empty');
        echo 'Error: URL is empty';
        return;
    }

    // Logging the data URL
    $dataUrl = site_url() . "/wp-json/wp/v2/prc/all_info";
    error_log('Data URL: ' . $dataUrl);
    echo 'Data URL: ' . $dataUrl . '<br>';

    // Fetch data from the WordPress REST API
    $response = wp_remote_get($dataUrl, array('timeout' => 120));

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('Error fetching data: ' . $response->get_error_message());
        echo 'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message();
        return;
    }

    $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    error_log('Fetched data: ' . $data);
    echo 'Fetched data: ' . $data . '<br>';

    $data_array = json_decode($data, true);

    if ($data_array === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        error_log('JSON decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
        echo 'Error: JSON decode error - ' . json_last_error_msg();
        return;
    }

    if ($data_array) {
        $data_array['strategy'] = [['strategy' => $strategy]];
        $data = json_encode($data_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        error_log('Data being sent: ' . $data);
        echo 'Data being sent: ' . $data . '<br>';
    } else {
        error_log('Invalid data format');
        echo 'Error: Invalid data format';
        return;
    }

    // Log the final data before sending
    error_log('Data to send: ' . $data);
    echo 'Data to send: ' . $data . '<br>';

    // Send data to the external URL using POST method
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'timeout'     => 300,
        'body'        => $data,
        'headers'     => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        )
    ));

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        $error_code = $response->get_error_code();
        error_log('Error sending data: ' . $error_message . ' (Code: ' . $error_code . ')');
        echo 'Error: ' . $error_message . ' (Code: ' . $error_code . ')';
    } else {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        error_log('Response from server: ' . $body);
        echo 'Response from server: ' . $body;
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>


Please explain how this would solve the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers
